# prevent user accessing site using server ip

Tags: apache, apache2.4

My Apache Server IP address is `192.168.1.50` and the Domain Name is `my.local`.  How do i restrict access to users using the IP address and not the server domain.

- A user that uses the domain `my.local` can access the site, **all files**
  should also be accessible.
- A user that uses the server IP `192.168.1.50`, should be redirected to the server domain, this being
  `my.local`.  So if that user went to `192.168.1.50/somepage.php` they
  would be redirected to `my.local`.  If a user went to
  `192.168.1.50/images/someimage.jpg`, they would be denied access.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward and flexible way is to create a separate virtual host with `ServerName 192.168.1.50`.  Just don't create it as the first virtualhost for any port, as it would become the default.

You can then use all the basic directives to redirect or perform access control, all in the context of 192.168.1.50.